# Using await/done in Protractor Cucumber Framework

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I am using below code snippet to print content in element id.However, the content is not printed as expected. In this post, I was asked to use await/done. I am quite new to this framework and wondering how can I use it.

[Empty response in Protractor console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52658462/empty-response-in-protractor-console-log)

```
var {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
var expect = chai.expect;

defineSupportCode(function ({And, But, Given, Then, When}) {

    Given(/^I launch Chrome browser$/, function () {

    var elm = element(by.id('the-basics'));
        elm.getText().then(function(txt) {
            console.log("txt: " + txt);
        });

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example of async/await

```
Given('I open Google`s search page', async () => {
  await client.url('http://google.com');
});
```

or done() function

```
Given(/I click something/, (done) => {
  // do stuff
  done();
}
```